# Jena eyeball validator: Scheme should be lower case

Tags: java, jena

I am using Jena eyeball validator. I want to validate some object from model and i am getting this response:

```
On statement:  C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\model4105427884345694181.rdf#_af24a682-0e40-11e7-9494-f0def1611578 cim:DiagramObject.IdentifiedObject C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\model4105427884345694181.rdf#_5c312cd0-0e3d-11e7-9494-f0def1611578
eye:badURI: "C:UserspcAppDataLocalTempmodel4105427884345694181.rdf#_af24a682-0e40-11e7-9494-f0def1611578"
for reason: scheme should be lower case
```

For some reason it deletes the \ from path and i can not find why.

I have successfully done this procedure with another profile which is smaller then this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, check does your rdf has xml:base

Answer (score 0):

An URI is expected, try to re-write the path like this:
`file://C/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/model4105427884345694181.rdf`